# NSArray - Filter all monopolies in parent-child relationship for a given player

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, filtering, nspredicate

I have an array of groups, with multiple children objects.

A `player` can own one (and only one) `child` object.  There is no link between the `parent` and `player` object.

I would like to filter all monopolies for a given player.

IE: Scenario

Parent array has 2 groups, *Group A* and *Group B*

```
1. Group A (array)
a. Child.owner = Player 1
b. Child.owner = nil
c. Child.owner = nil

2. Group B (array)
a. Child.owner = Player 1
b. Child.owner = Player 2
c. Child.owner = Player 3
```

In this above scenario, Player 1 has a monopoly in Group A.

How would I use NSPredicates to give me a list of all monopolies that a  given player has?

Many thanks

Comment: A monopoly in my game is a group where I am the only owner.

Comment: I have tried to use for-loops and a predicate; I will post code in a moment

Comment: Maybe a `NSSet *playersInA = [NSSet setWithArray:[groupA valueForKeyPath:@"Child.owner"];` and BOOL isThereMonopoleInA = ([playersInA count] == 1);

Comment: I will try it out, many thanks. Sorry for delay in posting code; I've been busy at work